# AndroidViewModel with parameters. Why is this working and could it cause future issues

Tags: android, viewmodel, factory, android-viewmodel

The reason why I am asking is because I've read that using a Factory is how you're supposed to pass arguments into a ViewModel, yet this implementation seems to be working fine.

My ViewModel

```
class MyListViewModel(application : Application , currentItemName : String) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val dataSource = Database.getInstance(application).DatabaseDao

    val itemList = dataSource.getItems(currentItemName)

    internal val _singleItem = MutableLiveData<Item>()

    val singleItem : LiveData<Item>
        get() = _singleItem

}
```

And here is how I initiate it in my Fragment

```
val currentItemName = "some item name"

val binding = FragmentItemsListBinding.inflate(inflater)

val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application

val viewModel = MyListViewModel(application, currentItemName)

binding.lifecycleOwner = this

binding.viewModel = viewModel
```

I'm happy if there are no downsides to this, but am a little concerned about creating other problems.

Answer (score 0):

> yet this implementation seems to be working fine

Perhaps you did not test a configuration change, such as:

- Rotating the device between portrait and landscape
- Toggling on or off dark mode
- Switching the locale in Settings
- And so on

The point behind using the Jetpack `ViewModel` system is to deal with configuration changes. And, for that, you need to use `ViewModelProvider` and let it manage creation of the `ViewModel`, whether using a built-in `Factory`, your custom one, or one provided by a dependency inversion framework (Dagger/Hilt, Koin, etc.).